# reflect.Field.annotations always null

Tags: java

I am trying to play with reflection and annotations.
For some reason whenever I add an annotation to a field (or a class or a method), and use reflection to look at the field, I see that its `annotations` field is null.

For example, this code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        System.out.println(Test.class.getField("bl").getAnnotations().length);
    }    
    @anno
    public int bl;    

    public @interface anno {}    
}
```

prints 0.

BTW, Java does not ignore annotations in general, and when (for example) I use the `@Deprecated` annotation - Eclipse recognizes it and tells me the class is deprecated.

I am using Eclipse Indigo and Java SE Development Kit 7 update 2.
Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By default, annotations are not available to reflection.  In order to do so, you need to change the retention policy, i.e.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Anno {}
```

The various retention policies can be found in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html). The default (for mysterious reasons that nobody seems to know) is `CLASS`.

Comment: @Ginandi: Nice of you to say so :)  Someone still thought it worth a downvote, mind you...

Answer (score 5):

I would check the @Retention e.g.

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Deprecated {
}
```

If you don't set it, it won't be visible at runtime.